# Why does ArrayList do this?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have several questions that need to be addressed. In this part of the code, 
al.add(1, "A2"); what does adding 1 do to the ArrayList? In the output, it doesn't look like adding 1 did anything to the arraylist. Also, in this part of the code, al.remove(2); seems to be removing A from the arraylist, but why is that? Shouldn't A be 3, since it's in the third place?

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // create an array list
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("Initial size of al: " + al.size());

        // add elements to the array list
        al.add("C");
        al.add("A");
        al.add("E");
        al.add("B");
        al.add("D");
        al.add("F");
        al.add(1, "A2");
        System.out.println("Size of al after additions: " + al.size());

        // display the array list
        System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
        // Remove elements from the array list
        al.remove("F");
        al.remove(2);
        System.out.println("Size of al after deletions: " + al.size());
        System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the codes:

```
Initial size of al: 0

Size of al after additions: 7

Contents of al: [C, A2, A, E, B, D, F]
```

Size of al after deletions: 5

```
Contents of al: [C, A2, E, B, D]
```

Comment: You are addin "A2" to the second position of the ArrayList?

Comment: Indexes in java start in 0, not 1.

Comment: I think you should read the API documentation for an ArrayList    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: **nmelssx** I have asked things more interested than this and I received 8 downvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477676/how-to-pass-a-temporary-anonymous-pointer-of-char-pointers-to-a-function

Comment: @cell, lol some people are jerks. It's not like I'm asking a dumb question on purpose.

Comment: @nmelssx I know, I understand you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
al.add(1, "A2");
```

added `A2` in index 1. Remember `ArrayList` starts with index 0 so the output is just right. Same thing with the `al.remove(2);`. It removes the 3rd item which is `E`.

Click the following links to [read more about the add method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)) and [remove method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)).

Answer (score 1):

The first index is 0.  When you add at position `1` it makes it the second item, and when you remove position `2`, you are removing the third position.

Answer (score 1):

The first param of al.add(1, "A2"); is The index.
so if i have something like this:

[C, A, E, B, D, F]

and i Add 
al.add(1, "A2");

I'l get  [C, A2, A, E, B, D, F]

for the second question.

and Array or a list starts from index 0
so its 
0 1 2 3 4....

so when I have this:

[C, A2, A, E, B, D, F]

C is in index 0
A2 is in index 1
and A is in index 2

so remove(2)
removes A

Answer (score 1):

ArrayLists and List all start from index 0, so when you do

```
al.add(1, "A2");
```

you are inserting `A2` at the second position and all other element below will be moved down.

Similarily when you remove `2` you are removing the third item and all items below will shift up the list

Answer (score 1):

Let's step through the code a bit...

```
al.add("C");
al.add("A");
al.add("E");
al.add("B");
al.add("D");
al.add("F");
```

Generates a list of

```
["C", "A", "E", "B", "D", "F"]
//0    1    2    3    4    5
```

Then...

```
al.add(1, "A2");
```

Adds `"A2"` to the position of `1` in this, so we now have a list of

```
["C", "A2", "A", "E", "B", "D", "F"]
//0    1     2    3    4    5    6
```

Then...

```
al.remove("F");
```

Which removes the entry `"F"` from the list...

```
["C", "A2", "A", "E", "B", "D"]
//0    1     2    3    4    5
```

And then...

```
al.remove(2);
```

Which removes "`A`" from the list, because "`A`" is the item at index `2`, remember, Java is zero indexed

```
["C", "A2", "E", "B", "D"]
//0    1     2    3    4
```

Take a closer look at:

- [The `java.util.List` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- [The Collections trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

for more details

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, almost all indices in Java will start from 0.

So if you have this array:

```
int[] example = {45, 33, 76, 21, 54};
```

Then example[1] is actually equal to the SECOND element - 33!

So, to give you more examples:

```
example[0] == 45 
example[1] == 33 
example[2] == 76 
example[3] == 21 
example[4] == 54
```

Now, lets talk about the method that is confusing you.

```
arrayList.add(index, item);
```

And that resulted in: Contents of al: [C, A2, A, E, B, D, F]

So here, the first thing that you pass in is the index. The second thing is the item. The index is where you are adding the new item. You will put the new item into that index, and move everything else back one.

So, in your example, you had:

```
arrayList.add(1,"A1");
```

The result was correct! The term "A1" was added in position index 1 (which remember, is actually the second spot in java, since you'll always start counting from 0), and everything else was pushed back by 1.

I hope this helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You should remember that Indexes start 0, but not 1. For Example,

```
List list = new ArrayList();

list.add("a");
list.add("b");
```

If you want to get the first element "a" in list, you have to do this:`list.get(0)`,but not `list.get(1)`